# Limit clicks on button based on user role

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a restricted page with entries for only-members in WordPress, and on this page there is a "View more" button for each entry. I'm looking for a solution, to limit clicks for that specific button depending on which user role the user has assigned. The button has its own class ".se-mere-knap".

For example user role 1 needs to have 5 clicks on this button from the time the subscription was created. If they reach the limit of clicks, they are not able to access any entries anymore by clicking the button. The subscriptions run for a month, and there are different unique users, so it needs to reset for that specific user when 30 days have passed from the start of their subscription.

I've made the code, based on user roles, for enqueue of the script to load the .js files in child theme functions.php:

```
     function add_custom_script_1() {
    
    if ( current_user_can( 'um_5-klik-test' ) ) {
        
    wp_register_script('custom_script_1', home_url() . '/button-restrict/button-restrict-5.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script_1');  
}
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_script_1', 999);
```

Secondly, wiht help from @Digi Coder, the button-restrict-5.js is as following:

```
"use strict";

    viewmore_settings();

    // checks if the expiry date has elapsed
    function check_viewmore_expiry() {
        // set the current date
        var curDate = new Date().getTime();
        // get the difference between the expiry date and current date
        var distance = localStorage.expDate - curDate;
        // round up to get the exact date remaining
        var days = Math.floor( distance / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) );
        // log remaining date to the console
        console.log( days + ' days left.' );
        // check if the expiry date has elapsed
        if ( distance < 0 ) {
            // log expiry message to the console
            console.log( 'Time Expired.' );
            // reset the expiry date to 30 days
            localStorage.expDate = new Date().setUTCSeconds( 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 );
            // reset the counter to zero
            localStorage.counter = 0;
        }
    }

    // disables view more button if counter limit is reached
    function viewmore_button_disabled() {
        // the html button that user clicks
        var btn = document.querySelector( 'button.se-mere-knap' );
        // check if user click action is up to five or greater than five
        if ( Number( localStorage.counter ) >= 5 ) {
            // disable the button
            btn.disabled = true;
            // button is disabled
            return true;
        }
        // button is not disabled
        return false;
    }

    // Sets value for the counter and expiry date stored in local storage
    function viewmore_settings() {
        // check for local storage support
        if ( typeof Storage !== 'undefined' ) {
            // check if counter is not set in storage
            if ( localStorage.counter === undefined ) {
                // set counter to zero
                localStorage.counter = 0;
            }
            // check if expDate is not set in storage
            if ( localStorage.expDate === undefined ) {
                // set expiry date to 30 days
                localStorage.expDate = new Date().setUTCSeconds( 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 );
            }
            // check if the expiry date has elapsed
            check_viewmore_expiry();
            // disable view more button if counter limit is reached
            viewmore_button_disabled();
        } else {
            // display message for browsers that does not support storage
            window.alert( 'Din browser understøtter desværre ikke vores funktioner.' );
        }
    }

    // runs when user clicks the view more button
    function viewmore_func() {
        // check for local storage support
        if ( typeof Storage !== 'undefined' ) {
            // check if the expiry date has elapsed
            check_viewmore_expiry();
            // check if the view more button is disabled
            if ( viewmore_button_disabled() ) {
                // display alert message for maximum click attempt
                window.alert( 'Din grænse for antal klik ind på en jobsøgendes profil er nået. Du kan opgradere til flere klik, gennem din virksomhedsprofil. Antal af klik bliver nulstillet hver 30. dag.' );
            } else {
                // increment counter for every user click action
                localStorage.counter = Number( localStorage.counter ) + 1;
                // log the counter value to console
                console.log( localStorage.counter );
                // redirect user to resource page or show user the content
                window.location.assign( 'index.php' );
            }
        }
    }

document.querySelector( 'button.se-mere-knap' ).addEventListener( 'click', viewmore_func );
```

I've created a user with this role to test with, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens when i exceed the limit of 5 click. No limit of clicks are set.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP

```
function add_custom_script_1() {
    // check if current user has capability of "um_5-klik-test"
    if ( current_user_can( 'um_5-klik-test' ) ) {
        // register custom_script_1
        wp_register_script('custom_script_1', home_url() . '/button-restrict/button-restrict-5.js', array( 'jquery' ));
        // enqueue custom_script_1
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_script_1');
        // localize custom_script_1
        wp_localize_script( 'custom_script_1', 'user',
            array(
                // set ID key to current user id
                'ID' => get_current_user_id(),
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_script_1', 999);
```

### HTML

```
<button class="se-mere-knap">View More</button>
```

### JavaScript - (button-restrict-5.js)

```
    "use strict";

    viewmore_settings();

    // checks if the expiry date has elapsed
    function check_viewmore_expiry() {
        // get stored data from local storage and convert from JSON string to original format
        var viewmore_data = JSON.parse( localStorage.viewmore );
        // loop through the stored data
        viewmore_data.forEach( ( item, index ) => {
            // check if the stored user match the current user
            if ( item.userID == user.ID ) {
                // set the current date
                var curDate = new Date().getTime();
                // get the difference between the expiry date and current date
                var distance = item.expDate - curDate;
                // round up to get the exact date remaining
                var days = Math.floor( distance / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) );
                // log remaining date to the console
                console.log( days + ' days left.' );
                // check if the expiry date has elapsed
                if ( distance < 0 ) {
                    // log expiry message to the console
                    console.log( 'Time Expired.' );
                    // reset the expiry date to 30 days
                    item.expDate = new Date().setUTCSeconds( 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 );
                    // reset the counter to zero
                    item.counter = 0;
                    // store data as JSON string in local storage
                    localStorage.viewmore = JSON.stringify( viewmore_data );
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    // disables view more button if counter limit is reached
    function viemore_button_disabled() {
        // set status to false: button is not disabled
        var status = false;
        // get data from local storage and convert from JSON string to original format
        var viewmore_data = JSON.parse( localStorage.viewmore );
        // loop through the stored data
        viewmore_data.forEach( ( item, index ) => {
            // check if the stored user match the current user and also check if click action is up to five or greater than five
            if ( item.userID == user.ID && Number( item.counter ) >= 5 ) {
                // select all button with the class of view-more, typecast them to array and loop through them.
                [...document.querySelectorAll( 'button.se-mere-knap' )].forEach( ( btn, index ) => {
                    // hide the button
                    btn.style.display = 'none';
                } );
                // set status to true: button is disabled
                status = true;
            }
        } );
        // return the value of status
        return status;
    }

    // Sets value for the counter and expiry date stored in local storage
    function viewmore_settings() {
        // check for local storage support
        if ( typeof Storage !== 'undefined' ) {
            // set expiry date to 30 days
            var expDate = new Date().setUTCSeconds( 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 );
            // set counter to zero
            var counter = 0;
            // set user id
            var userID = user.ID;
            // create object containing expiry date, counter and user id
            var data = { expDate, counter, userID };
            // check if no data is stored in local storage
            if ( localStorage.viewmore === undefined ) {
                // put data object inside an array
                var viewmore_data = [ data ];
                // store data as JSON string in local storage
                localStorage.viewmore = JSON.stringify( viewmore_data );
            } else {
                // get data from local storage and convert from JSON string to original format
                var viewmore_data = JSON.parse( localStorage.viewmore );
                // get all stored user ids from data
                var users_id_arr = viewmore_data.map( ( item, index ) => {
                    return item.userID
                } );
                // check stored user ids does not match the current id
                if ( users_id_arr.indexOf( userID ) === -1 ) {
                    // append new object containing expiry date, counter and user id to data
                    viewmore_data.push( data );
                    // store data as JSON string in local storage
                    localStorage.viewmore = JSON.stringify( viewmore_data );
                }
            }
            // check if the expiry date has elapsed
            check_viewmore_expiry();
            // disable view more button if counter limit is reached
            viemore_button_disabled();
        } else {
            // display message for browsers that does not support storage
            window.alert( 'Your web browser does not support local storage' );
        }
    }

    // runs when user clicks the view more button
    function viewmore_func() {
        // check for local storage support
        if ( typeof Storage !== 'undefined' ) {
            // check if the expiry date has elapsed
            check_viewmore_expiry();
            // check if the view more button is disabled
            if ( viemore_button_disabled() ) {
                // display alert message for maximum click attempt
                window.alert( 'You have reached the limit!' );
            } else {
                // get data from local storage and convert from JSON string to original format
                var viewmore_data = JSON.parse( localStorage.viewmore );
                // loop through stored data
                viewmore_data.forEach( ( item, index ) => {
                    // check if the stored user match the current user
                    if ( item.userID == user.ID ) {
                        // increment counter
                        viewmore_data[index].counter = Number( item.counter ) + 1;
                    }
                } );
                // store viewmore data array as JSON string in local storage
                localStorage.viewmore = JSON.stringify( viewmore_data );
                // redirect user to resource page or show user the content
                // window.location.assign( 'index.php' );
            }
        }
    }

    // select all button with the class of se-mere-knap, typecast them to array and loop through them.
    [...document.querySelectorAll( 'button.se-mere-knap' )].forEach( ( btn, index ) => {
        // add event that will run when the button is clicked
        btn.addEventListener( 'click', viewmore_func );
    } );
```

Comment: Thanks alot! The button doesn't have a # but a class. How can I make sure that the code will only work for the specific button with this class (.view-more)?
I'm quite new in this segment - how can i set `var counter` and `var expDate` to let's say a local storage?

Comment: For class names, assume the button class name  is **.view-more**, set `var btn` like this: `var btn = document.querySelector( 'button.view-more' );` .

Comment: Okay, thanks! How can I set and call this from a local storage or cookie? In order for it to be dynamic.

Comment: @markpnielsen I have edited my answer. You can now call from local storage. enjoy :-)

Comment: Thanks @Digi Coder! I see your HTML with the `onclick="viewmore_func();"`. My button is generated with another plugin, where i can't seem to edit the button HTML. I can only set custom CSS class for it. How to fix this?

Comment: @markpnielsen add this to the bottom of your **custom_script_1** and **custom_script_2**  `document.querySelector( 'button.view-more' ).addEventListener( 'click', viewmore_func );`

Comment: Thanks, it's added in the bottom now of the .js. But unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've updated and edited my question with your code, and corrected button class, but nothing happens when the limit of clicks exceeds. Can you please take a look at it again?

Comment: Okay, i got it to work now for the specific user role! But it only works with a self-made HTML button with the right class - as the HTML code you wrote. The button that is made with the plugin, or even if  i make a button with the theme with a custom class it doesn't work. Is there a way to fix this? @Digi Coder

Comment: I don't know why it does'nt work with your plugin button. I suspect that **button-restrict-5.js** is not enqued on the same page with the plugin button.

Another thing to note is that `document.querySelector` only selects one unique HTML element. So if you want to select multiple button with class **se-mere-knap**, you will have to change `document.querySelector` to `document.querySelectorAll` and loop through the buttons. I have edited my answer to address this issue. Observe the changes in `function viemore_button_disabled()` and at the bottom of the bottom of the script.

Comment: It's working now for the right button, but after clicking "OK" to the alert it just redirects to the page/entry instead of staying on same page when limit is exceeded. 
Is there a way to hide the button when the limit is exceeded? Instead of window.alert @Digi Coder

Comment: To hide the button when the limit is exceeded, you'll have to change `btn.disabled = true;` to `btn.style.display = 'none';` inside **viewmore_button_disabled** function.

Comment: It works now, the button is hidden if the user have exceeded the limit. But i testet it again by creating a new user, with same user role, and this user has also exceeded the limit without clicking the buttons? It should only count clicks per unique user so one user can't effect the other users click count. Maybe i need to add some additional code the functions.php in my child theme? For it to check user id? @Digi Coder

Comment: @markpnielsen In your **functions.php**, you will need to localize **custom_script_1** and set an object ( `user` ) containing the user id. The `user` object will be available in **button-restrict-5.js**, and stored along with the expiry date and counter in local storage. I have updated my answer to your question. Notice I store an array containing each user data as a **JSON string** in the browser storage, and convert them back to it's original format  when working with the data.

Comment: Okay thanks! I've updated my code now. I created a new user again, with same role, but the limit of clicks are still exceeded for the new user without clicking the buttons. What could be the problem? And when i use the `wp_enqueue_script` it doesn't load when the page loads. It loads after clicking the button which makes the button disappear after clicking it. If the limit is reached, it shouldn't show the buttons. Maybe i need to set priority different? @Digi Coder

Comment: @markpnielsen I hope your WordPress version is up to date. In your functions.php, change `wp_register_script('custom_script_1', home_url() . '/button-restrict/button-restrict-5.js', array( 'jquery' ));` to `wp_register_script('custom_script_1', home_url() . '/button-restrict/button-restrict-5.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true);`, for your JavaScript to be enqueued in the footer section, and not in the head section. Also change the priority of  `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_script_1', 999);` to default priority `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_script_1')`;

Comment: Also try using a new browser or deleting all cookies and local storage, so that the new changes will appear. I suspect the old script is still taking effect on your browser, that's why it's hiding the button even for a new user.

Comment: YesWP is up to date. It works now! Thanks alot @Digi Coder. 
Though i noticed that i for some reason increments with +2 for every click on button. So for the limit of 5 i need to set it to 10 in the js file. It's the same for Chrome, Firefox and Edge - with cookies and local storage cleared. Wouldn't it be better to store this in the database, if someone thinks of clearing their cookies? Which will reset the click count if they do

Comment: Yes @markpnielsen it's best to store in database than local storage.

Comment: Can we catch up on e-mail (markpnielsen@yahoo.dk)? If we could take an online session soon regarding storing in database, it would be great. And also send what your hour rate is for helping, if you're interested in helping with the database solution. @Digi Coder

Comment: That'll be great.